# Wording of a Modified Post

Tags: feature-request, design

A couple of days (maybe weeks) ago the wording of an edited post was changed from *edited* to the screenshot below (*modified*):.

[image]

Why not change that into:

<strike>*modified by Jacob Jan Tuinstra 7m ago 6728*</strike>?

*[action] [elapsed time] [word] [word] [user] [reputation]*

example:

*modified 7 min ago `by` Jacob Jan Tuinstra 6728*

<sub>Should've been my first attempt.....</sub>

Comment: @pnuts yes, you are right

Answer (score 2):

Then you would be breaking the information presented. Currently it's of the format:

> action time user reputation

Your proposed would be

> action user time reputation

The "action time" pair is as closely related as "user reputation" are.

Putting "time" between user and reputation would then be wrong since time is relative to the action taken, not the reputation or the user.

Comment: Ok, what about my new proposal? Would this give any problems?